# Best way to upload a file to a non-public S3 bucket without exposing access key

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static website hosted on an S3 bucket. The website takes a file as an input and uploads it to another S3 bucket. I don't want to keep the bucket as public. How can I upload a file to a non-public bucket? Currently, I'm using my access key to upload a file, but I don't want to expose the access key in my Javascript code for authentication. My objective is to upload a file to a non-public bucket without exposing my access credentials.

Edit1:
I used the amazon API gateway with Lambda to generate pre-signed S3 URL. This way my credentials don't get exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to hide API Keys for Javascript. [React and Node examples](https://medium.com/@asbillings2007/hide-your-api-keys-71e7bab3af69)

You could also use  [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to store the API Keys.  There are examples of how to integrate with node.js and other frameworks.